# set indent of a table while building it with reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm trying to build a report with Reportlab in Python, it works rather allright. Hence I cant find the command for setting the indent of the table (on the canvas not the indent within the cells).

I want to move the table to the left, the `leftIndent` doesn't do anything? (Or did I just implementet it wrong?)

```
table = Table(data, repeatRows=1, hAlign='LEFT', colWidths=[380/nr_heading_items] * nr_heading_items)
table.setStyle(TableStyle([('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (l_heading, 0), 16), ('leftIndent', 10)]))
story.append(table)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Move the table to the left as in left aligned next to the left margin?

Set `colWidths=['*']`. That will force the table to use the full page width and will automatically align it to the left.